# Cannot revert a downvote even though the author edited their answer after I downvoted

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17620328

I read this answer and didn't like it, so I downvoted.  I also commented why I left the downvote.

Later, the user edited the post to such a degree that I'm willing to revert the downvote (though I still won't upvote).

However I can't because:

> You last voted on this answer 22 mins ago Your vote is now locked in
>   unless this answer is edited

But the user did edit?

Comment: Looks like, from the system's POV, the edit was before the downvote. Edit: 17:14:23, your comment 17:14:45, if you can type faster than I, the downvote could indeed have been after the edit was registered, but before you saw it.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Hmm...

Comment: So is the only way I can revert this by gaming the system?  In other words, I'll go in and edit it myself, then revert?

Comment: Or it could be that the original edit was smaller, and then expanded in the grace period, but after your downvote. Looking at the revisions and your comment, that seems not unlikely. Well, to retract your downvote now, you have to get somebody to edit the answer. You could do it yourself, ask Yu Hao to edit, so you can retract, wait for somebody else to edit ...